# !default css font-family specificity tag

Tags: html, css, webpack, font-family

I am using local css-modules in react/webpack to build some local fonts in a dev environment.

I see this !default tag added to my computed styles in all browsers  which invalidates all css font-family rules.

Files received by the browser under sources in Chrome do not have this tag.

How can I remove this !default string? Or further debug in chrome.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea, but does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10643107/1016716) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer had to do with a webpack version update and css-module. Thanks for the comment @Mr-Lister I did learn a thing. Hope someone else who comes across an issue with the webpack dependency web and can know just to pin the version so there are no minor semver upgrades.

[github link 1](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/issues/1027)

[github link 2](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3018#issuecomment-248378677)