# My custom.scss file is not taken into account in Bootstrap 4 alpha 6

Tags: css, html, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm doing a tutorial to learn Bootstrap 4 (alpha 6). I need to customize the original css configuration from bootstrap.

For this I have modified the _custom.scss:

```
// Bootstrap overrides
//
// Copy variables from `_variables.scss` to this file to override 
default values
// without modifying source files.
$green:red;
```

I then recompile the bootstrap.scss file (I'm using prepros) and when I reload the page, nothing has changed. When I look to the generated bootstrap.css file the color is still the default green color from bootstrap main theme.

When I modify the _variables.scss file directly it works perfectly.

In my bootstrap.scss file the _custom.scss file is imported after _variables.scss :

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "custom";
```

Does anyone have a clue on why this isn't working ?

Comment: [Bootstrap uses SCSS `!default`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643107/what-does-default-in-a-css-property-value-mean) to set variables. Try importing `custom` _before_ `variables`.

Comment: Can you post your variables document please?

Comment: I 'll update my post this evening. But the variables file is the default provided by bootstrap, I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer.

It was a misunderstanding of how Sass works. I thought that these variables was like in java : a reference. But it is not the case here in sass so you have to redefine also the components using the color variable like this :

```
$green:red;

$brand-success:$green;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, my _custom.scss wasn't seems to be working while compiling, but actually its its a very simple fix.

copy _variables.scss content and paste into _custom.scss file and simply remove all `!default;` from the whole file.

`$font-size-h1: 2.5rem !default;`

to

`$font-size-h1: 2.5rem;`

will fix the issue.